# Appending Strings for Image Loading CSHTML

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working with ASP.net MVC for a website page in cshtml. I'm new to this & I'm having a hard time doing a simple task as I would in C#. I'm trying to load images onto my site by a field in my "categories" class. There is a field in this class called ImageFileName.

I'm able to load an image normally hardcoding like:

```
<img src="~/Content/Images/Dining/Dining.jpg"  
     alt=@c.CatName 
     style="width:64px;height:48px;" />
```

However, I want to do the same without hardcoding the file name:

```
<img src="~/Content/Images/" + @c.ImageFileName 
     alt=@c.CatName 
     style="width:64px;height:48px;" />
```

However this does not append the path string and the files do not load. I have tried putting the images in the general images folder as well, I just feel I have the wrong syntax.

Comment: Why not put this logic in a viewmodel then just bind to that property?

Comment: I am not how I would accomplish it this way, how would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're syntax is incorrect.  Remember, you're rendering HTML and writing in Razor, not C#.

This:

```
<img src="~/Content/Images/" + @c.ImageFileName 
     alt=@c.CatName 
     style="width:64px;height:48px;" />
```

Should be this:

```
<img src="~/Content/Images/@c.ImageFileName" 
     alt="@c.CatName"
     style="width:64px;height:48px;" />
```

However, as others have suggested, you might consider storing the whole path of the image in that `ImageFileName` property.  Your code would then be:

```
<img src="@c.ImageFileName" 
     alt="@c.CatName" 
     style="width:64px;height:48px;" />
```

Just some food for thought

Comment: That was simple. Thank you for your help and input.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (**using Html.Raw helper)**:

```
<img src="@Html.Raw("~/Content/Images/" + c.ImageFileName)" 
 alt="@Html.Raw(c.CatName)" style="width:64px;height:48px;" />
```